# Define array from html data automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a problem with defining array from HTML data automatically.

Here is my data:

```
<div id="events">
    <div id="blabla" data-title="Five K for charity" data-date="01/13/2013"></div>
    <div id="bleble" data-title="Dinner" data-date="01/25/2013"></div>
    <div id="Div1" data-title="Meeting with manager" data-date="01/01/2013"></div>
</div>
```

And I want to define an array like this:

```
var events = [
        { Title: "Five K for charity", Date: new Date("01/13/2013") },
        { Title: "Dinner", Date: new Date("01/25/2013") },
        { Title: "Meeting with manager", Date: new Date("01/01/2013") }
    ];
```

I can get the data from that like this:

```
$("#events > div").each(function (index) {
        console.log("{ Title: " + "\"" + $(this).data("title") + "\", " + "Date: new Date(\"" + $(this).data("date") + "\") }");
    });
```

But I dont know how to "print" them into that array. Is there a way how to do that?

I'll be glad for any answer :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var events = [];

$("#events > div").each(function (index) {
    events.push({
        Title: $(this).data("title"),
        Date: new Date($(this).data("date"))
    })
});
```

Comment: `Date` is probably not a good name for a property key (probably not even legal?)

Comment: Since `Date` is no keyword it should work. Changing the name would be different from the original requirements of the question. But yes, I would also recommend using a different name for the attribute.

Comment: Oops, bikeshedder is right, I should check my sources better. Date is ok to use, but +1 to try to find another.

Comment: fyi. `Date` is not listed as reserved word in the MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing at the moment is forming them as some fragile JSON format.

Instead you should be creating an object literal directly;

```
$("#events > div").each(function (index) {
   var obj = { 
       Title: $(this).data("title"), 
       Date: new Date($(this).data("date")) 
   };
});
```

And to get it in an array you could use [jQuery's `map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map):

```
var ar = $("#events > div").map(function (index) {
   return { 
       Title: $(this).data("title"), 
       Date: new Date($(this).data("date")) 
   };
});
```